# Use Google Apps and Transactional MTA, saving sent emails

Tags: g-suite, email-server

I've been researching for the following problem I have and I cannot find a clear solution:

The company I work for needs to send around 200-300 billing emails out to customers 2 or 3 times a week. Right now this is done manually via Outlook or the Gmail web interface and it takes ages of course.

We have email set up on a free, grandfathered Google Apps account. As far as the billing guys can tell, they are not hitting any sending limits. The Gmail daily sending limit seems to be 500. Also,  because they are doing it manually, maybe they are not triggering any alarms on Google's side.

I was tasked with writing a quick application that would automate these emails, so the 200 emails would go out at once, but I am afraid that we will hit some sort of Gmail sending limit soon. I am looking at using an external MTA (like Mandrill or Sendgrid) just for sending out these emails out in bulk.

The address that the emails go out from is something like billing@example.com . The billing guys send, receive and interact with customers from this email address, so they need to have a record of all email sent from this address in their "Sent" folder in Gmail or Outlook.

As far as I can tell, if I use a separate MTA for sending some emails, there is no way to save or merge these in to my Gmail account. Am I right? Is there any workaround that I can use?

Thanks,
Rafael

Comment: Could you CC/BCC them to `billing@example.com` and have a rule to move them to the Sent folder?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, that is one possibility, although I think that would duplicate the amount of emails I would be sending out, thus duplicating costs. I would have to ask the external MTA about this.

Comment: Mandrill has 12k free sends monthly. At 200-300 2-3 times a week that's 3,600 a month at most. Doubling that would still leave you at only about half the free tier limit.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm considering this option. The company is growing and the emails are increasing but it might still be a while until we hit the 12k limit. Thanks for your comment!